# Clarification on size of Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

I was under the impression that if $K/k$ is Galois then $G$ the Galois group of this extension had the size of the degree of the extension. However, I don't think this is correct anymore. Under what circumstances is this true? I think this is true for number fields? Because if $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois number field then we can express $K$ as $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ which means we each automorphism in $G$ corresponds to where we send $\alpha$ to among its $n$ conjugates where $n = [K:\mathbb{Q}].$ In particular, if $K/k$ is Galois and $K = k[\alpha]$ I guess this would be true but are there other notable examples for which this is true?

Do all finite Galois extensions have this property? I suspect this is true as we can write such an extension as the base field adjoined with finitely many elements. But I am not sure about the other cases...for example infinite Galois extensions? I have not encountered such examples yet.

Comment: All finite Galois extensions are separable and simple so they have this property by more or less the same argument you used for number fields. Infinite Galois extensions [don't have this property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059658/11619). The group may have a higher cardinality than the extension degree. Linking to that thread mostly because while trying to answer it I dug up links to other related threads. I'm afraid it's not really too well organized.

Comment: Also you should try starting with this definition : $K/k$ Galois iff $k = K^G$ (the subfield fixed by $G$) for some finite subgroup $G \le Aut(K)$. Normal and separable means you can always find $\sigma \in Aut(K/k)$ moving $\alpha \in K,\alpha \not \in k$ so $K/k$ is Galois. From $k = K^G$ you know all the minimal polynomials.

Comment: As I understand things, infinite Galois groups are always uncountable. The extensions, not so.